# Strange regex behavior when matching with strings that include dots

Tags: python, regex, perl, python-2.7

I have a following case where the matching seems to not work properly:

```
import re

test_case1 = u"I will meet you at 2 pm"
test_case2 = u"I will meet you at 2 p.m."
test_case3 = u"I will meet you at 2 p.m. "
test_case4 = u"I will meet you at 2 p.m. pm "

list_of_words = ['p.m.', 'pm'] # list of words that can be enlarged

# join all words into an or expression and escape all punctuation
joined_words = '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list_of_words]) 
# create a regex that will match a word from the list of words only if it is 
# at the start/end of the sentence or it is between two word boundaries
match_regex = r'(^|\b)('+joined_words+r')(\b|$)'
comp_regex = re.compile(match_regex, re.IGNORECASE) # compile the final regex

print comp_regex.findall(test_case1), len(comp_regex.findall(test_case1))
print comp_regex.findall(test_case2), len(comp_regex.findall(test_case2))
print comp_regex.findall(test_case3), len(comp_regex.findall(test_case3))
print comp_regex.findall(test_case4), len(comp_regex.findall(test_case4))
```

I get the following results for the 4 test cases:

```
[(u'', u'pm', u'')] 1
[(u'', u'p.m.', u'')] 1
[] 0
[(u'', u'pm', u'')] 1
```

The 1st and 2nd cases seem to work fine, 3rd doesn't match "p.m." if there is space after it, even though I have used "\b" word boundary in the regex.

The 4th case doesn't seem to match the "p.m." at all and only matches the "pm".

I can't seem to understand where the problem lies, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) state following about `\b`:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of **alphanumeric or underscore** characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string, so the precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags. For example, r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'. Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

According to that definition `.` can't mark the end of the word so `\b` doesn't match after `p.m.`. If you make following change to your match you get the behavior you expect:

```
match_regex = r'(^|\b)('+joined_words+r')(\s|$)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try :

```
match_regex = r'(^|\b)('+joined_words+r')(\s|$)'
```

If you want the p.m and pm at the last line : [example](http://pythex.org/?regex=%28%5E|%5Cb%29%28pm|p.m.%29%28%5Cs|%24%29&test_string=I%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20pm%0AI%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20p.m.%0AI%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20p.m.%20%0AI%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20p.m.%20pm%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

or

```
match_regex = r'(^|\s)('+joined_words+r')(\s|$)'
```

if you want the first p.m. only : [example](http://pythex.org/?regex=%28%5E|%5Cs%29%28pm|p.m.%29%28%5Cs|%24%29&test_string=I%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20pm%0AI%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20p.m.%0AI%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20p.m.%20%0AI%20will%20meet%20you%20at%202%20p.m.%20pm%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)